Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin for multiple serviceroutes via a single web.config in IIS
I have a website that offers 3 serviceroutes that is written in MVC and running under IIS.  When I set things like Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, etc. this is done via the web.config and it sets it for all serviceroutes.  Is is possible to set these values for each serviceroute via the web.config via the <httpProtocol><customHeaders> or would have to set these in code per serviceroute and add them as user defined values in the <appSetting><add key>.
When I say serviceroutes I mean:
https://mywebsite/service1
https://mywebsite/service2
https://mywebsite/service3
I don't want to hard-code any of these values beyond them being in the web.config file.  And I don't have the option of re-writing this as 3 separate services/websites. :-)

From what I have searched and tested, this cannot be done in the web.config file.
